# How Do I Write Data To A SQLite Database Using Adobe Air?

Tags: sqlite, adobe, air

I'm absolutely struggling with this. I am building an application using Adobe Air that will allow us to vote on calls we receive (such as is the call a sales call, complaint, or a query about a product) and save these votes for viewing later on.

I've built the interface with all the radio buttons, and it has compiled successfully, but that is as far as I've managed to get. I don't know if it is loading the database that I have provided and even if I knew this I don't know how to get it to write the data to the database.

I've used Google and a lot of websites it lists don't go over how to insert and retrieve data using Adobe Air with SQLite (even though I'm lead to believe this is the database Adobe have packaged with it).

Any help on this I would be very grateful for.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look on the following:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883989/basic-crud-in-adobe-air-flex

http://www.12robots.com/index.cfm/2009/7/14/Using-SQLite-Databases-with-AIR--Series-Introduction

http://devworks.thinkdigit.com/Features/Using-an-SQLite-database-in-an-AIR_6471.html

Comment: Cheers, I will look in to this :)